# How do I get past this Kihunter cocoon after reloading a save?

Tags: metroid-fusion

I'm at the point in Metroid Fusion where you have to restore auxiliary power to the station. I saved at the ship and proceeded through fine. I successfully got to the spider boss once, died, and when I reloaded the save, the Kihunter cocoon just to the left of the docking bay was still wriggling and I couldn't get past it. How do I get it to leave the cocoon?

Screenshots:
[image: The secret entrance is to the left in this room]
The secret entrance is to the left in this room.

[image: And this is what I'm greeted with upon entering. The cocoon is impassable in this state.]
And this is what I'm greeted with upon entering. The cocoon is impassable in this state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My best guess is that you hit save when you entered the ship, which actually saves before the dialogue with Adam giving you the objective to go to the auxiliary power.  That dialogue is probably what triggers all of the cocoons to hatch, so if you reloaded from the save, you need to run to the left or right a bit and then run back under the ship so that you can trigger the dialogue again.

Comment: You'd think it'd do the dialog first, but now that you mention it, I think it does save first.  On a side note, it always annoyed me that the save room closer to that boss is disabled until after you beat said boss.

Comment: Especially because that boss is very tricky!